# Is it possible to crawl flash websites

Tags: java, php, flash, web-crawler

I wish to crawl a flash website and screenshot each page periodically.

Simply is it possible to crawl a website running fully in flash?

Can this be achieved in Java or PHP, and if so is there any useful material around to aid me in this process.

Would be greatful for any help on this matter, Many Thanks

EDIT: it is also worth noting that the links and buttons change every few hours on the website

Comment: Use a computer with a script, like AutoIt, which opens the website in a browser and creates a screenshot?

Comment: IMHO flash-only websites deserve poor crawler-coverage.

Comment: @LucFranken that was the plan, looking at AutoIt now, my concern is that the links and buttons change often on this site so it wouldnt be a simple cycle of the same pages

Comment: If you have a screenshot you can write a smarter algoritm offcourse which detects buttons if you know their style. You could also click every x pixels for example as a test to see if you get another image. There are tricks available. An alternative could be some tool which makes it possible to extract content from the swf like http://www.nowrap.de/flare.html. No solution would be really "Great" since the files are not really open, but there are tricks to get to some point which should make it possible.

Comment: good question; i develop only crawlers/scanners/monitors and i never thinked to monitor e flash website

Comment: i've obtain and inspected the .swf files with little to no joy on locations of buttons and so on.

might have to try to detect buttons

Answer (score 0):

You can't get a screenshot client-side, and certainly not with PHP. PHP runs on your server, not on the client.

Comment: the method i was thinking of was running an application on client side that would open a flash website (through a browser) and navigate through each page and screenshot

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PhantomJs](http://phantomjs.org).

Although they have removed Flash support from v1.5, but you can use previous versions or use a fork with Flash support like this one: [putting-the-flash-back-in-phantomjs](http://www.ryanbridges.org/2013/05/21/putting-the-flash-back-in-phantomjs/)